# How get one record in DB2 using cics and cobol program

Tags: db2, cobol, cics

I have a table called `room_table`

```
room_no room_status  room_type
-------|-----------|----------
1001   | A         |single
1002   | A         |single
1003   | B         |single
```

I am using following code in CICS COBOL program but I am getting SQL `error code -811`

```
    select room_no 
    from room_table 
    where room_status='A' 
      and room_type ='single'
    fetch first 1 row only
```

I have used cursor concept too but it returns `error code -311`

Any idea?

Comment: Apart from the fact that your statement is syntactically incorrect (the `select first...` clause is invalid), it could not possibly result in either SQLCODE -811 or -311.

Comment: Agree, run it through SPUFI or QMF to check.  -311 was from the cursor (which we do not see here).  Q's been edited after the comment above.
Are you testing the SQLCODE or a variable it has been moved to ? Did the move happen ? You should not get a -811 with first row only.  What are you selecting INTO ?  Has this query been paraphrased ?

Answer (score 1):

This would of been answered before but:

1. Use a cursor and only fetch the first record, see [Cursor](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_rowretrievalwithcursor.htm)
2. Use **group by**

```
       
     Select min(room_no) from  room_table 
      where room_status='A' and room_type ='single'
     group by room_status
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using DB2 [**Fetch-first-clause**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_fetchfirstclause.htm#db2z_sql_fetchfirstclause)?

replace `select first 1 row only` with `fetch first row only`

Comment: sorry i used fetch first 1 row only

Answer (score 0):

-311 is not -811 : Something is wrong with a host variable.

For -811 we would "fetch first row only".

Now,

prior to this feature being available, many coders ignored IBM's warnings and simply allowed -811 as OK, as a value was somehow always returned (albeit without guarantee). I would hope that any such code has long been touched up.